# All AADSTS codes related to certificate issues

Tags: adal

We are working on a project which uses Adal library. We received different AADSTS error codes. For example, we received ADSTS700027: Client assertion contains an invalid signature, because we didn't add the thumbprint of the certificate to AAD allowed list. In another scenario, we received AADSTS700030: Invalid certificate, because we didn't allow thumbprint-based authentication. The root causes for these two AADSTS codes are very similar. I am wondering if there is a full list of AADSTS codes that are related to certificate so that we can catch such exceptions and handling them.

Comment: There is no specific AADSTS error code for the certificate. The official document gives a [list of all the error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes#aadsts-error-codes). Or you can use the Azure AD [error query page](https://login.microsoftonline.com/error).

Comment: Hi, I will post a comment as an answer to end the thread, if my answer is helpful to you, you can accept it as an answer, it may help others. ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments:

There is no specific **AADSTS** error code for the certificate. The official document gives a [list of all the error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-aadsts-error-codes#aadsts-error-codes). Or you can use the Azure AD [error query page](https://login.microsoftonline.com/error).